Trigger a flow only when AssignTo column is updated
I have a flow that I ONLY want triggered when the Assigned To column in my SP list is updated. The flow works fine but will update and send an email with an attachment when any other column is updated. I only want the flow to run when Assigned To is updated. The person assigned should receive an email with an attachment from the SP list.
I tried using trigger outputs @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Assigned_x0020_To'], true) AND @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Assigned_x0020_To/Value'], 'true') in the settings for "When an item or file is modified" and that didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Unfortunately, there is no dedicated trigger for SharePoint list column changes. Also, you cannot check if the column value is changed or not directly using the trigger conditions (settings of trigger - "When an item or file is modified").
Hence, you will have to let the flow run without any condition in trigger settings and then inside the flow, check if column value is changed or not using "Condition" action. Based on the condition, you continue the flow if column value is changed or terminate the flow if column value is NOT changed.
You can check if the column value is changed or not by using "Get changes for an item or file" action.
Example:



Source: Power Automate SharePoint Get Column Changes - detailed information in blog and video.
Similar threads:

Conditionally trigger flow based on the previous value stored in the column
Triggering flow when column in SharePoint List is edited

